# Is my cpu damaged, or is there something else wrong

Tags: cpu, motherboard, cooling, cpu-temperature, cpu-throttling

I have had this problem for a month now; let me explain how and when it began exactly

one day in some spring vacation, I had turned off my computer for the night after gaming with a few friends on it; the next day, it would barely turn on.. it had even caused the power circuit in the room to be shut down after I turned the computer on, so I had to mess around a bit to find out why.
I did not know immediately what the issue was, I tried messing around a little, took off several cables and reconnected them, removed the CPU fan, the back fan, and a front fan and cleared them of dust and debris, and gave the motherboard a cleaning as well; and then I turned on the computer, and now it had caused the electricity to go out again.. i noticed there was a spark in the PSU area, and then I knew precisely what the issue was.. apparently, a loose screw managed to find its way into the PSU, and caused it to literally short circuit, it was no longer operational

My PSU Had broken, and I had changed it from the 500w I had to a CORSAIR TX Series CMPSU-650TX 650W, and that is when the problem began.

Although I did not notice it as I was busy with life and such, I barely even touched this piece of scrap once the PSU was changed; whenever I did, I noticed that the computer was underperforming massively after said change in the PSU;

I have an Intel I5-3450, with a stock speed of 3.1 GHz, the thing is, whenever I'm running a heavy task, like playing a video game, or even watching some HD video, the computer would lag quite a lot, it would not go above 0.8 GHz no matter what
after a while, I installed several programs to diagnose the problem, such as CPU-Z.
from what I noticed, the computer keeps reading temperatures way above 50 Celsius.
now, something definitely is wrong, so I contacted Gigabyte about the issue (the motherboard's manufacturer). they haven't really helped much other than telling me to update drivers, clean the computer and update bios, I did all of those, and I still have the same problem.

it's been 2 weeks now and from what I searched online, it seems the computer is giving me false readings of the temperature, and as a result, would throttle down to prevent damage to the CPU, I even made sure that there is no actual heat and took off the side lid to check the heatsinks, they were just slightly warm to the touch, not like the 104 celsius the computer kept reading, hell, even the air coming back off of the back fan is warm enough if not colder than the air around.

I have tried everything I can and I'm starting to get desperate, I might even do a whole, full-on restart to the computer, but I want that to be the last option as I have many files stored all around.

if I could get any kind of help, advice or just suggestion, it'll be nice; LMK if I should provide any more information to help

**Edit 1:** The CPU has not been touched at all, I have only touched the cpu's fan and heatsink and gave them a clean. I'll try to set the heatsink tightly after putting some thermal paste..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your problem can be explained in 3-4 lines. Writing the whole "saga" will turn people away from this.

Comment: im just trying to get the best possible solution man

Comment: So, in order to achieve that goal, be assertive, for starters. And in all that rambling, tangents and irrelevant info, not once you mentioned whether or not you touched the CPU (+fan + heatsink) therefore I suggest [edit]ing and keep only what's relevant and if you did something to the CPU part just say so. Very likely that's the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In modern Intel processors, the temperature sensing and thermal throttling decision both happen inside the processor itself, so the motherboard or software actions cannot easily make it go wrong. Of course, if the processor was subjected to significant overvoltage by the PSU failure, anything can happen.

If the processor is reporting a high temperature and limiting processor speed ("throttling") while the CPU heatsink does not feel at all warm, that most likely means the heat is not transferring from the CPU into the heatsink. The overwhelmingly most common reason for this is a misaligned heatsink or other heatsink installation error.

The heatsink should be tightly against the top of the processor, with only just enough thermal paste to fill any tiny irregularities between the two surfaces.

If you did remove the heatsink from the motherboard while cleaning the motherboard, are you sure you put it back **exactly** the way it was? Some heatsinks have a step in their bottom surface to leave space for capacitors next to the processor. If you didn't install the heatsink in the correct orientation, one edge of the heatsink might be resting on top of the capacitors, causing the heatsink to only touch the processor at the opposite edge, instead of the whole processor surface as it should.

If you did not remove the heatsink, its screws (or other attachment mechanisms) could still have worked themselves loose while you were cleaning the motherboard, allowing the heatsink to get out of position.

Sometimes one can be blind to one's own mistakes, or just not know where exactly to look: if possible, find someone else who's familiar with building desktop PCs and have them take a look at your system. They might notice something you keep missing.

Comment: I'll try it out! thanks